# windowShouldClose return false, but window closed

Tags: swift, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nswindow

i need do something in background when user click the red x at upper left of NSWindow,

NSWindowDelegate method windowShouldClose(_:) return false, but the window close. and the GCD closure never call.

the console log is 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 7, and i want it be 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 4 - 7.

what's the problem of the code?

EDIT:
In face, i want window just hidden when user click red x, and i will do something background, and then close window after 1 second.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        print("1")
        if sender.isVisible {
            print("2")
            sender.orderOut(nil)
            // do something here
            print("3")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("4")
                sender.close()
            }
            print("5")
            return false
        } else {
            print("6")
            return true
        }
    }

    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("7")
    }

}
```

Finally:

1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 4 - 7

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        print("1")
        if sender.isVisible {
            print("2")
            sender.orderBack(nil)
            // do something here
            print("3")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("4")
                sender.close()
            }
            print("5")
            return false
        } else {
            print("6")
            return true
        }
    }

    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("7")
    }

}
```

Thanks for Malik and Parag Bafna.

Comment: I tried your code and I get 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 4 - 7, as expected, `close()` doesn't call `windowShouldClose()`. Is the background task closing the window? Why do you want `windowShouldClose()` to be called again?

Comment: it's weird. running that test code, my console is always 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 7. and background task will do nothing about window.

Comment: Do you want to run the background task when the window closes or when the app quits?

Comment: i want to terminate app after last window close. and i have to release `Reachability()`'s observer in my real project before app can terminal. nor app will crash. but the test project has nothing with `Reachability`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderOut` call inside `windowShouldClose` is creating the issue.
Use `orderBack` and `isKeyWindow` check

```
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    print("1")
    if sender.isKeyWindow {
        print("2")
        sender.orderBack(nil)

        // do something here
        print("3")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print("4")
            sender.performClose(nil)
        }
        print("5")
        return false
    } else {
        print("6")
        return true
    }
}
```

or return false from `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`

Comment: cool. replace `orderOut ` with `orderBack ` get the right result. but `isKeyWindow` is not correct check, people can click red x without window is key. and need to use `close()` instead of `performClose()` , that will cause dead circle.

Comment: the key is **orderOut call inside windowShouldClose is creating the issue**, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close)

> The close method posts an willCloseNotification notification to the default notification center.
>
> The close method differs in two important ways from the performClose(_:) method:
>
> - **It does not attempt to send a windowShouldClose(_:) message to the window or its delegate**.
> - **It does not simulate the user clicking the close button by momentarily highlighting the button.**
>
> Use **performClose(_:)** if you need these features.

In the light of the above, try updating your code to as follows

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        print("1")
        if sender.isVisible {
            print("2")
            sender.orderOut(nil)
            // do something here
            print("3")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("4")
                sender.performClose(nil) //THIS IS THE KEY
            }
            print("5")
            return false
        } else {
            print("6")
            return true
        }
    }

    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("7")
    }

}
```

Comment: console never log 4 -> the GCD closure never call.

Comment: I tried this code on my machine and it is printing the expected output originally mentioned in your question (1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 6 - 7). Try creating a new empty project and pasting this code. If it works, then there might be something wrong with any additional code in your current project. If it still doesn't work, try removing `Derived Data` and execute a `clean` before running it again

Comment: as your suggest, i `Clean Build Folder`,  and running without `4`; delete all file in Xcode `Derived Data`, also running without `4`. all test code was paste from you. any advice?

Comment: That's bizarre. I literally created a new project with this code and it worked. Can you perhaps upload the new project somewhere (maybe GitHub) and share a link so I can have a look?

Comment: i upload the test project at [link](https://github.com/joguo/testGCD.git) without gitignore file.